# How to use java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit; in jdk 1.4?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, jdk1.4

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

`TimeUnit` is not supported in my version of Java. How to implement the above logic in JDK 1.4 ?

When I am importing `TimeUnit` like in the statement below it is saying "can't find symbol concurrent". It is happening in the intellij IDE.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

Comment: Short answer is you can't use JDK 1.4. The Selenium driver is compiled against later Java versions.

Comment: `java.util.concurrent` package was added in Java 1.5. What you're asking is impossible to do.

Comment: JDK 1.4. I'm curious – why are you using 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Wikipedia - Java class file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) the published numbers are:

```
Java SE 14 = 58 (0x3A hex)
Java SE 13 = 57 (0x39 hex)
Java SE 12 = 56 (0x38 hex)
Java SE 11 = 55 (0x37 hex)
Java SE 10 = 54 (0x36 hex)
Java SE 9 = 53 (0x35 hex)
Java SE 8 = 52 (0x34 hex)
Java SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex)
Java SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex)
Java SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex)
JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex)
JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex)
JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex)
JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex)
```

Currently you are using *...JDK 1.4...*

---

### Solution

As the minimum requirement to compile `org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver` class file is **Java 8** you have to upgrade **JDK** to the minimum support level, preferably at current level of [JDK 8u271](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).